# Error when using std::unique_ptr and inline Functions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml, c++20

I am currently writing a Statemachine for SFML in C++ 20. The Statemachine has been working so far, but when I decide to make use of modules I get a problem with the functions CreateState, DestroyState and Run! These functions were outline in an cpp file, as soon as I make these inline I get Errors, but making them outline don't work in modules!

Code:

```
module;
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <assert.h>

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

export module Game;

class Gamestate;

template<class T>
concept Gamestates = std::is_base_of<Gamestate, T>().value;

export class Game
{
public:
    Game()
    {
        m_window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML WINDOW");
        m_windowColor = sf::Color::Black;
    }

    ~Game()
    {
        DestroyState();
        m_window.close();
    }

    template<Gamestates T>
    void Run() {
        load<T>();
        Run();
    }

    sf::RenderWindow& getWindow() { return m_window; }
    sf::Color& getWindowColor() { return m_windowColor; }

    float getDeltaTime() { return m_deltaTime; }
    float getFPS() { return (1.f / getDeltaTime()); }

private:
    sf::RenderWindow m_window;
    sf::Color m_windowColor;

    std::unique_ptr<Gamestate> m_state;

    sf::Clock m_deltaClock;
    float m_deltaTime;

    template<Gamestates T>
    void load()
    {
        if (m_state)
            DestroyState();

        m_state = std::make_unique<T>();

        CreateState();
    }

    void CreateState()
    {
        m_state->Create(*this);
    }

    void DestroyState()
    {
        m_state->Destroy(*this);
    }

    void Run()
    {
        float lastTime = 0;

        while (m_window.isOpen())
        {
            m_state->Update(*this);

            sf::Event event;
            while (m_window.pollEvent(event))
            {
                m_state->HandleEvents(*this, event);
            }

            m_window.clear(m_windowColor);

            m_state->Draw(*this);

            m_window.display();

            float currentTime = m_deltaClock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
            m_deltaTime = currentTime - lastTime;
            lastTime = currentTime;
        }
    }
};

// DON'T CALL ANY PURE VIRTUAL FUNCTIONS IN THIS CLASS
export class Gamestate
{
public:
    virtual void Create(Game& game) = 0;
    virtual void Destroy(Game& game) = 0;

    virtual void HandleEvents(Game& game, sf::Event& events) = 0;
    virtual void Update(Game& game) = 0;
    virtual void Draw(Game& game) = 0;

    virtual std::string GetName()
    {
        return "Gamestate";
    }

    virtual ~Gamestate()
    {
        std::cout << "State: \"" << GetName() << "\" destroyed!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Errors:

```
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(65,1): error C2027: Verwendung des undefinierten Typs "Gamestate"
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(11): message : Siehe Deklaration von "Gamestate"
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(65,12): error C2039: "Create" ist kein Member von "std::unique_ptr<Gamestate,std::default_delete<Gamestate>>".
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(47): message : Siehe Deklaration von "std::unique_ptr<Gamestate,std::default_delete<Gamestate>>"
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(70,1): error C2027: Verwendung des undefinierten Typs "Gamestate"
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(11): message : Siehe Deklaration von "Gamestate"
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(70,12): error C2039: "Destroy" ist kein Member von "std::unique_ptr<Gamestate,std::default_delete<Gamestate>>".
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(47): message : Siehe Deklaration von "std::unique_ptr<Gamestate,std::default_delete<Gamestate>>"
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(79,1): error C2027: Verwendung des undefinierten Typs "Gamestate"
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(11): message : Siehe Deklaration von "Gamestate"
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(79,13): error C2039: "Update" ist kein Member von "std::unique_ptr<Gamestate,std::default_delete<Gamestate>>".
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(47): message : Siehe Deklaration von "std::unique_ptr<Gamestate,std::default_delete<Gamestate>>"
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(84,1): error C2027: Verwendung des undefinierten Typs "Gamestate"
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(11): message : Siehe Deklaration von "Gamestate"
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(84,14): error C2039: "HandleEvents" ist kein Member von "std::unique_ptr<Gamestate,std::default_delete<Gamestate>>".
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(47): message : Siehe Deklaration von "std::unique_ptr<Gamestate,std::default_delete<Gamestate>>"
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(89,1): error C2027: Verwendung des undefinierten Typs "Gamestate"
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(11): message : Siehe Deklaration von "Gamestate"
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(89,13): error C2039: "Draw" ist kein Member von "std::unique_ptr<Gamestate,std::default_delete<Gamestate>>".
1>D:\git\SpaceXGame\SpaceX\src\Game.cpp(47): message : Siehe Deklaration von "std::unique_ptr<Gamestate,std::default_delete<Gamestate>>"
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have a derived class implementing any of the pure virtual functions.

Also make the constructor of such a baseclass protected. That way nobody can accidentally instantiate it.

Comment: I solved the problem by change the definition order of Game and Gamestate! And thanks for the Answer!